# Can't deconstruct base parts

Tags: subnautica

I am in the process of relocating a base, not far away up on a more stable part of ground. Most of the deconstruction has been fine, however there are a few parts, including an empty multipurpose room, and some basic corridors that I get a weird message:

> Can't deconstruct None. None must be deconstructed first.

I get that this is alpha/early access and it may just be a bug, but another weird thing happened as well. This base was fine before the last couple updates, but now one of the tunnels has this weird black mass inside.

[image]

This doesn't look anything like the surrounding terrain, which previously was automatically terraformed when the corridor was placed. Now I can't get through this corridor, and the other end is up next to rock so I cannot add a hatch or anything to get to it. This corridor also gets the same message as above. (I should note that there are no terrain issues with the multipurpose room that gets this message.) I also check and there are no structural issues, or places that need repaired from what can be seen.

Any suggestions? I'd love to be able to get the resources back, there is not a lot of titanium in this region, and really want to clean up the old base.

Comment: Well first of all, you should report that to the developerswith the contact developers button.
Do you have any objects inside this room that you forgot to remove ?

Comment: I planned on reporting it as a bug if it wasn't something blatant that I was doing wrong -- even though I didn't think that was the case. No, there are no objects in that corridor. I was able to put a hatch in the top and other side, (and later removed it) and still no dice.

Comment: Just thought of something, try to get your structure damaged by yourself or a sea monster, maybe it'll do something

Comment: I've had a similar bug before, and I was able to fix it by rebuilding that part of my base (fixing it back to 100%) before trying to remove it again.

Comment: It didn't have any effect. I ended up just creating a new game anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the removal of terrain modification from the game.  It looks like you built into the terrain and now the original terrain has come back there is a collision which the game is interpreting as an object still constructed inside your module.

Comment: This was a couple years ago, and it happened almost immediately (after saving/reloading the next day) so it's not related to the terrain mod changes. It ended up being a bug according to the developers that was later fixed.